# BecomeFirstResponder make searchBar return to initial frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisearchcontroller

I've created a view which ease in on button click on top of the navigationBar. i've then added a searchController to this View. i've then changed the frame of the searchBar so it fits the view. However when the searchBar `becomeFirstResponder`, it returns to initial frame? How can i avoid this?

**ViewDidLoad**

```
    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(10, 8, self.view.frame.width - 20, 28)
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Default
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    //        searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    searchView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
```

**Search Button Clicked**

```
func searchButtonClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {

        self.searchView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height)



        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in


    })
}
```

**not first responder**

[image]

**FirstResponder**

[image]

Comment: At what point is becomeFirstResponder called?

Comment: Try calling sizeToFit for the searchBar and don't set it's frame yourself.